# post_type incorrect for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, search

I am trying to display a different template depending on the post type.

I have registered two custom post types called `resource` and `contact`. When I try to get the post type in search.php (using `get_post_type()`), I always get back `resource` post type, even when the post is definitely `contact`.

Registering `resource`

```
function register_resource_post_type() {

    $args = array(
        'labels' => array('name' => __('Resources'), 'singular_name' => __('Resource'), 'add_new_item' => __('Add New Resource')),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'custom-fields' ),
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'rest_base' => 'resource-api'
    );

    register_post_type('resource', $args);

    function custom_enter_resource_title( $input ) {
        if ( 'resource' === get_post_type() ) {
            return __( 'Enter resource title' );
        }

        return $input;
    }
    add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'custom_enter_resource_title' );
}
add_action('init', 'register_resource_post_type');
```

Registering `contact`

```
function register_contact_post_type() {

    $args = array(
        'labels' => array('name' => __('Contacts'), 'singular_name' => __('Contact'), 'add_new_item' => __('Add New Contact')),
        'public' => true, 
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'custom-fields' ),
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'rest_base' => 'contact-api'
    );

    register_post_type('contact', $args);

    function custom_enter_contact_title( $input ) {
        if ( 'contact' === get_post_type() ) {
            return __( 'Enter contact title' );
        }

        return $input;
    }
    add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'custom_enter_contact_title' );
}
add_action('init', 'register_contact_post_type');
```

Search.php

```
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            $post_type = get_post_type() <---- THIS IS ALWAYS resource
        endwhile;
```

Comment: Have you tried `get_post_type( get_the_ID() );` ?

Comment: Yep. I get the same post_type.

Comment: I ran everything you have and it's all working as expected. I'm sure you've already done this, but I would go back and make sure your content is published and your search term matches the title you're looking for correctly. If that all looks right, go back to the raw query and see if you can run the raw mysql query from `$wp_query` on the database and get a different result.

Comment: `get_post_type()` is not a complicated function. Unless you're deliberately filtering it somewhere else, if it says the post type is `resource`, it is. Mike is right, you need to make sure you're publishing as the correct post type.

Comment: Can you share more about your while loop? If you're using `$post_type` outside of (after) the loop, then it will always be the post type of the very last post, because it's overwriting itself for each post. If you're using it inside the loop, do you have other queries running on this page and maybe need to do a `wp_reset_query()` before this loop?

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was the comment by https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/39152/jacob-peattie that made me think of disabling some plugins. It looks like the Relevanssi plugin might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment

> get_post_type() is not a complicated function

led me to disable the Relevanssi plugin that I was using for search and determined that "Create custom search result snippets" setting had been selected and was causing issues with the post type being returned. Once I unchecked this, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another possible solution for anyone else struggling with this. Removing the category of the post from the permalink - e.g. setting wordpress to use ONLY the post name - will cause this function to always return "post" for all custom post types.

You can avoid this by adding the category to the permalink in Settings->Permalink. If you still don't want the category to show, remove it with a plugin like redirection.